# Django - Where are the params stored on a PUT/DELETE request?

Tags: django, rest, parameters

I'd like to follow the RESTful pattern for my new django project, and I'd like to know where the parameters are when a PUT/DELETE request is made.

As far as I know, I only see GET & POST QueryDict in the request, no others.
Is Django adding a new PUT or DELETE QueryDict regarding to the request, or does it add the parameters to GET or POST QueryDict ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I am using django v1.5. And I mainly use **QueryDict** to solve the problem:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
put = QueryDict(request.body)
description = put.get('description')
```

and in *.coffee

```
$.ajax
      url: "/policy/#{policyId}/description/"
      type: "PUT"
      data:
        description: value
      success: (data) ->
        alert data.body
      fail: (data) ->
        alert "fail"
```

You can go [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) to find more information. And I hope this can help you.

Comment: For modern versions of Django, this is much more helpful than the accepted answer.

Comment: When I do put = QueryDict(request.body) it prints out as: 

<QueryDict: {u"{'content_id': '2', 'draft': 'True', 'id': '2', 'title': 'Hello Changed World'}": [u'']}>

It is like it is saving the data I am sending as a key.

Comment: Will something like "request.META.get('REQUEST_METHOD','').upper()" won't give us 'PUT' or 'DELETE' as mentioned in https://gist.github.com/g00fy-/1161423?

Comment: Also, do we need to do something like "request.parse_file_upload(request.META,request)" to parse 'multipart' requests.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: kind of lame from django that we still have to use that workaround in 2017. Any decent web framework should embed such support...

Answer (score 48):

I assume what you're asking is if you can have a method like this:

```
def restaction(request, id):
    if request.method == "PUT":
        someparam = request.PUT["somekey"]
```

The answer is no, you can't. Django doesn't construct such dictionaries for PUT, OPTIONS and DELETE requests, the reasoning being explained [here](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/msg/b5a73fd98848ff9b).

To summarise it for you, the concept of REST is that the data you exchange can be much more complicated than a simple map of keys to values. For example, PUTting an image, or using json. A framework can't know the many ways you might want to send data, so it does the obvious thing - let's you handle that bit. See also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500434/using-django-rest-interface-with-http-put) where the same response is given.

Now, where do you find the data? Well, according to the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.raw_post_data), django 1.2 features `request.raw_post_data`. As a heads up, [it looks like django 1.3 will support](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.read) `request.read()` i.e. file-like semantics.

Comment: As of Django 1.4, ``request.raw_post_data`` has been renamed ``request.body``, and ``raw_post_data`` was removed in Django 1.6.

Comment: Actually you can make Django handle PUT and DELETE requests as you like. Here you can find a [possible approach](https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/put-and-delete-http-requests-with-django-and-jquery/).

Comment: This Malcom in the google thread has by far no understanding of what he is talking about, his justification is ridiculous. The fact that the Django Core team did not even dare implementing such support in 11 years is awful...

Answer (score 14):

Ninefiger's answer is correct. There are, however, workarounds for that.

If you're writing a REST style API for a Django project, I strongly suggest you use [tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie). You will save yourself tons of time and guarantee a more structured form to your API. You can also look at how tastypie does it (access the PUT and DELETE data).

Answer (score 9):

There was a problem that I couldn't solve how to parse multipart/form-data from `request`. `QueryDict(request.body)` did not help me.

So, I've found a solution for me. I started using this:

`from django.http.multipartparser import MultiPartParser`

You can get data from `request` like:

```
MultiPartParser(request.META, request, request.upload_handlers).parse()
```

Comment: This worked for me in Django 1.8. Definitely the best answer when handling file uploads with PUT.

Answer (score 5):

You can see an example of getting a QueryDict for a PUT method in [django-piston's code](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/c4b2d21db51a/piston/utils.py) (See the coerce_put_post method)

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to override the dispatch function so I can set a variable from the body data using QueryDict()

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import QueryDict
from django.views.generic import View


class GenericView(View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
            handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)

            # if we have a request with potential body data utilize QueryDict()
            if request.method.lower() in ['post', 'put', 'patch']:
                self.request_body_data = {k: v[0] if len(v)==1 else v for k, v in QueryDict(request.body).lists()}
        else:
            handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)


class ObjectDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, GenericView):

    def put(self, request, object_id):
        print("updating object", object_id)
        print(self.request_body_data)

    def patch(self, request, object_id):
        print("updating object", object_id)
        print(self.request_body_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django cannot access params in the body of `PUT` request easily. My workaround:

```
def coerce_put_post(request):
"""
Django doesn't particularly understand REST.
In case we send data over PUT, Django won't
actually look at the data and load it. We need
to twist its arm here.

The try/except abominiation here is due to a bug
in mod_python. This should fix it.
"""
if request.method == "PUT":
    # Bug fix: if _load_post_and_files has already been called, for
    # example by middleware accessing request.POST, the below code to
    # pretend the request is a POST instead of a PUT will be too late
    # to make a difference. Also calling _load_post_and_files will result 
    # in the following exception:
    #   AttributeError: You cannot set the upload handlers after the upload has been processed.
    # The fix is to check for the presence of the _post field which is set 
    # the first time _load_post_and_files is called (both by wsgi.py and 
    # modpython.py). If it's set, the request has to be 'reset' to redo
    # the query value parsing in POST mode.
    if hasattr(request, '_post'):
        del request._post
        del request._files
    
    try:
        request.method = "POST"
        request._load_post_and_files()
        #body = request.body
        request.method = "PUT"
    except AttributeError:
        request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST'
        request._load_post_and_files()
        request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'PUT'
        
    request.PUT = request.POST


@api_view(["PUT", "POST"])
def submit(request):
    coerce_put_post(request)
    description=request.PUT.get('k', 0)
    return HttpResponse(f"Received {description}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the parameters are in the URL, you can still use `self.request.GET` to get parameters for PUT and DELETE methods.

For example

```
DELETE /api/comment/?comment_id=40 HTTP/1.1
```

In the APIView you can do this:

```
class CommentAPIView(APIView):

    # ... ...

    def delete(self, request):
        user = request.user.id
        comment_id = self.request.GET['comment_id']
        try:
            cmt = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=comment_id, user=user)
            cmt.delete()
            return Response(status=204)
        except Exception, e:
            return Response({'error': str(e)})
```

Comment: You can't, at least in Django 3.2.15

Comment: **Late edit:** Actually you _can_, for me the issue was probably with DRF's `APIClient`. Not sure what happened (and don't have the time to investigate) but apparently in my case it only works if I explicitly change the URL; passing query params as `data` or otherwise doesn't work with `APIClient`.