# Getting PATCH request parameter in Django

Tags: django, http, rest, http-headers

Is it possible to retrieve the request parameters of a HTTP PATCH request in Django? `request.method == 'PATCH'` is recognised, but I struggle to retrieve the request payload. I've tried `request.REQUEST.items()`, but this didn't contain any data. I know I could use Django-tastypie, but in this case, I would like to avoid it (and I supposed tastypie is using some Django methods to retrieve this data anyway).

I'm using Django 1.5.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - Where are the params stored on a PUT/DELETE request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994789/django-where-are-the-params-stored-on-a-put-delete-request)

Comment: @falsetru: I don't think this is a duplicate question (this one is about `PATCH` - people (like me) may not find this link when looking for `PATCH`). Nevertheless, thanks for the link - `raw_post_data` did the trick (I used it before, but forgot it existed).

Comment: I find above question using `PATCH`, `django` as search keyword.

Comment: I don't - at least not in the first 250 search results on SO.

Comment: Still, there's no mention about `PATCH` at this link (and SO didn't suggest it when writing this question either). Anyway, I don't mind if this gets closed...

Comment: I think you are looking for  `request.data`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a QueryDict class manually.  This is class implemented in django and processing all text data received through http request.

Link on the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

And here is an example of usage:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

def home_view(request):

    if request.method == 'PATCH':
        data = QueryDict(request.body)
        print data['your_field']
```

Answer (score 2):

As @asitm9 mentioned, using `request.data` works for `POST`, `PUT` and `PATCH` and is recommended.

Comment: Which version of Django are you talking about?

Comment: `request.data` doesn't contain anything

Comment: Answer probably assumes that DRF is installed, which provides `request.data`. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#request-objects

Answer (score 1):

Just try to use MultiPartParser when the CONTENT_TYPE is "multipart/form-data;",else QueryDict.

```
if request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', '').startswith('multipart'):
   from django.http.multipartparser import MultiPartParser

   query_dict, multi_value_dict = MultiPartParser(request.META, request, 
                                                  request.upload_handlers).parse()
else:
   from django.http import QueryDict

   query_dict = QueryDict(request.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

> raw_post_data did the trick (I used it before, but forgot it existed)