# WSGIRequest object has no attribute PUT

Tags: python, json, django, wsgi, put

I'm trying to make a put request to the local server using the put request using curl:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"connid":"12"}' "127.0.0.1:8000/api/kill"
```

I receive the same response:

> 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'PUT'

for the following code:

```
def kill(req):
  conid = req.PUT['connid']
  statusres = {}

  if conid in state:
    error[conid] = 'true'
    statusres['status'] = 'ok'

  else:
    statusres['status'] = 'invalid connection Id : '+ conid
  return JsonResponse(statusres)
```

I also used `@csrf_exempt` before the function.

Comment: What is `req`? Is this a Django view? The argument is usually called `request`. Either way, what makes you think it has an argument called `PUT`?

Comment: req is the request object . yes this is a django view.. here  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994789/django-where-are-the-params-stored-on-a-put-delete-request) @DanielRoseman

Comment: Yes. Did you read that link? It explicitly says you can't do this. But you don't want to anyway, given that you are sending JSON.

Comment: i miss read that. do i need to specify put as method to the request explicitly @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 8):

You have misunderstood several things here.

When you send form-encoded data, whether it's POST or PUT, in Django you always find the parameters in `request.POST`. So you would find your data in `request.POST['conid']`.

However, you are *not* sending form-encoded data; you are sending JSON. You need to access the request body, and pass it to the `json.loads` function to decode:

```
def kill(request):
  data = json.loads(request.body)
  conid = data['connid']
```

Comment: ...thanx a lot !

Comment: It is clean and short.