# Middleware logging limitation Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, integration-testing

**Background:**
I have integration test which is working fine, but later on failed when I 
added the customized `middleware`

```
def test_mobile_update_customer(self):
    user = User.objects.create(username='warhead')
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=user)
    mommy.make(Customer, family_name='IBM', created_user=self.soken_staff, updated_user=self.soken_staff)
    data = {
        "family_name": "C0D1UM"
    }
    customer = Customer.objects.first()
    res = self.client.patch(reverse('api:customer-detail', kwargs={'pk': customer.id}), data=data)
    self.assertEqual(200, res.status_code)
    customer.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual('C0D1UM', customer.family_name)
    self.assertEqual('spearhead', customer.created_user.username)
    self.assertEqual('warhead', customer.updated_user.username)
```

**Problem:**
The middleware break it with `Exception`

```
  File "/Users/el/Code/norak-cutter/soken/soken-web/soken_web/middleware.py", line 47, in process_request
    data['PATCH'] = json.loads(request.body)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/soken/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 264, in body
    raise RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")
django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

The problem is `data` has been read before the `RESTful` api do the job.
Then the program raises an exception.

```
def process_request(self, request):

    if request.path.startswith('/api/'):
        data = collections.OrderedDict()
        data["user"] = request.user.username
        data["path"] = request.path
        data["method"] = request.method
        data["content-type"] = request.content_type
        if request.method == 'GET':
            data['GET'] = request.GET
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            data['POST'] = request.POST

        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994789/django-where-are-the-params-stored-on-a-put-delete-request
        # elif request.method == 'PUT':
        #     data['PUT'] = json.loads(request.body)

        # test_mobile_update_customer
        # raise RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")
        # django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
        # elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        #     data['PATCH'] = json.loads(request.body)
        elif request.method == 'DELETE':
            pass
        self.__uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        request_logger.info(f'{self.__uuid} {json.dumps(data)}')
```

**Update2**
**Attempt:**
I change `client` constructor refer to https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2774

```
def test_mobile_update_customer(self):
    user = User.objects.create(username='warhead')
    # self.client.force_authenticate(user=user)
    from django.test import Client
    client = Client()
    client.force_login(user)
    mommy.make(Customer, family_name='IBM', created_user=self.soken_staff, updated_user=self.soken_staff)
    data = {
        "family_name": "C0D1UM"
    }
    customer = Customer.objects.first()
    res = client.patch(reverse('api:customer-detail', kwargs={'pk': customer.id}), data=data, content_type='application/json')
    self.assertEqual(200, res.status_code)
    customer.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual('C0D1UM', customer.family_name)
    self.assertEqual('spearhead', customer.created_user.username)
    self.assertEqual('warhead', customer.updated_user.username)
```

It does not work. The `Client` misinterpret the payload

```
>>> res.content
b'{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"}'
```

**Workaround:**
I don't know this is correct for all cases or not, but I workaround by this
`test.py`
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/88eb7c90cfca1c369a020ac232c7fbcc
`middleware.py`
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/5d9b1a2f890a0efcb46fdb95c0e90908
`result.py`
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/298e595b404c1a5839ed8dd584d2f07f

**Question:**
How do I do integration test of `PATCH` with the same time that testcase will not break by my middleware?

Right now I have to choose either one of them.

Comment: You haven't set `content_type` in your `client.patch()` call like the [example you linked to](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2774). I believe you have to convert the data dictionary to json using `json.dumps` as well.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you for you reply. I started to giving up on this. It looks like  Django fundamental mechanics limitation. How do you `log` all payload of traffice to your system?. Payload can be `json`, `form`, `form+file`

Comment: @Alasdair I have added my workaround. Could you please have a look?

Comment: I don't understand why you added `content_type` to `force_login()`. You need to add it to `client.patch()`.

Comment: If I use `django.test.Client` it misinterpret the payload. Then I have follow the docs http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient
Currently workaround is find. But I am not sure it will break by `file` or not. When I have time I will update on this question.