# How can I handle PUT requests in django? (not in drf)

Tags: python, django, request, put

I tried to get data from PUT requests in this way

`name = request.PUT["name"]`

but it cause error :

`'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'PUT'`

I don't know how to get data from PUT requests in only django style (rest framework)

Comment: have you tried `request.data`? (from the documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing)

Comment: @PerunSS there is no way to do it without rest framework?

Comment: It can be done, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994789/django-where-are-the-params-stored-on-a-put-delete-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to access some key in a PUT request you can do this:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
put = QueryDict(request.body)
name = put.get("name")
```