# Django: Getting 403(csrf token validation error) If I make POST/PUT request one after other

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have page where I render datatables to display the data with buttons like edit and delete per row,I have also one global button to create new entry. The create button opens a modal form which is standard bootstrap model.
I am using this same form to create & update records.So if refresh my page & create one new entry it works but without refresh when click on the edit button then submit the modal form it gives me this error,

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

All this operations are performed using the AJAX request so I am not reloading the page after each request.How can I resolve this?
Here is my server side code you want to take a look,

```
class CategoryView(AdminLoginRequiredMixin,View):
    
    def post(self, request):
        form = DownloadableCategoryForm(request.POST)

        if not form.is_valid():
            return JsonResponseBuilder.validation_error(form.errors)

        form.save()
       
        return JsonResponseBuilder.success('Category created succesfully...')

    # to update category
    def put(self, request):
        try:
            category = DownloadableCategory.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('id'))
        except DownloadableCategory.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponseBuilder.error('Category not found!', HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND.value)

        form = DownloadableCategoryForm(request.POST,instance=category)

        if not form.is_valid():
            return JsonResponseBuilder.validation_error(form.errors)

        form.save()
        
        return JsonResponseBuilder.success('Category updated succesfully...')
```

Here is my JS code which I am using to create/update records

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'admin:create_downloadable_category' %}",
                    method: id.length == 0 ? "POST" : "PUT",
                    data: new FormData(form[0]),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('.pre-loader-screen').fadeIn(200);
                    },
                    
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        error = JSON.parse(err.responseText)

                        swal(
                            {
                                title: "Error!",
                                text: error['message'] || 'Internal Server Error!',
                                type: "error",
                                showCancelButton: true,
                                closeOnConfirm: true,
                            })

                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        categoryModal.modal('hide')
                        $('.pre-loader-screen').fadeOut(200);
                        reloadDatatable()
                        toastr.success(response.message);
                    }
                });
```

Edit: I came to know that update method is not working even if I refresh the page & try to update the records. It just giving me 403 error.

Comment: I believe that AdminLoginRequiredMixin requires to be logged-in to access this endpoint. However, AJAX call does not contain authentication.
How do you authenticate AJAX call?

Comment: AJAX calls are authenticated if your session is.

Comment: Its a web app so it is already taken care of by cookies

Comment: Can you show the code for FormData and where you are getting the variable form[0] from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

Comment: Also `pk=request.POST.get('id')` I don't think this would work in a PUT request.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat why?

Comment: @RopAliMunshi because it contains the POST parameters only. If you want to get parameters for a PUT request [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994789/django-where-are-the-params-stored-on-a-put-delete-request) might help you,

Comment: Thank you all for your response. I have created a separate view for the update & it fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should render the modal content from the server. When user clicks on the modal to create/update the object at that time you have to fire AJAX call for the updated modal content and update the modal content.

You should create a AJAX view which gives you a modal content.

Comment: I dont think I have to render all the modal content as I am rendering the csrf token.

Comment: As per your requirements, you can either get only csrf token from the server through AJAX and update in the modal.

Comment: @PriteshSuvagiya CSRF token doesn't change within a session unless some settings have been changed

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request, You have to send the CSRF TOKEN in headers while using the AJAX request.